# How does `:visited` pseudo class get overridden by `:link` pseudo class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was reading about [`:visited` pseudo class on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) and they said that `:visited` pseudo class can be overridden by `:link` pseudo class:

> The :visited CSS pseudo-class lets you select only links that have been visited. This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes, that is :link

I am not able recreate this feature. I tried two scripts. One with `:link` mentioned before `:visited` and then the other way round but both the scripts work the same. In the following script the `:link` pseudo class doesn't override the `:visited` pseudo class -- The anchor element becomes red when it is visited not green.

```css
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
a:link {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.hello.com">Go to Hello.com </a>
```

So, how does `:visited` pseudo class get overridden by `:link` pseudo class? Would there be any observable difference if `:link` is declared after or before `:visited` in the style sheet?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is a slight error in the documentation.

The real problem is that, if visited, the :link pseudo class no longer aplies ,**in any case**

> The :link CSS pseudo-class lets you select links inside elements. This
>   will select any link which has not yet been visited,

cited also from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link)

So, in your examples, :link won't work in **any** case, no matter what you do, once the link is visited

Comment: But this is obvious. This is what `:visited` is supposed to do. I thought mentioning `:visited` before `:link` would override `:visited` in such a way that the the properties would be solely determined by `:link` pseudo class no matter whether the link is visited or not -- but it doesn't happen. Ordering of `:link` and `:visited` doesn't matter. `:link` styles only unvisited links and `:visited` styles the visited ones. They are both mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user31782: "But this is obvious." So what is your point, exactly? How does this answer not address your question?

Comment: @BoltClock The answer exactly addresses my question. By _But this is obvious_ I meant that it is so obvious that _if visited, the :link pseudo class no longer applies_.